# Variance for mixed distribution (continuous + discrete)

Tags: probability, statistics

> A random variable X has the cumulative distribution function:
>
> $F(x)=
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{l}
> 0 \text{ for x < 1}\\ 
> \cfrac{x^2-2x+2}{2} \text{ for } 1 \le x <2\\ 
> 1 \text{ for } x \ge 2
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $
>
> Calculate the variance of x.

I know the definition of variance is:  $Var[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ so we proceed by calculating each term.

$E[X]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx\tag{1}$

$E[X^2]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx\tag{2}$

So to evaluate equations (1) and (2), we need to calculate the PDF.  This is where I am confused.  I know the PDF is the derivative of the CDF.  Also, we note that $F(2)-F(1) = 1/2$ and by definition $F(\infty)=1$.

This forces the probability for $x<1$ to be 1/2.  Is this correct?  How would we write the system of equations for the PDF below?  I don't really see how this is a combination of discrete and continuous if the limits are $(x<1), 1 \le x < 2, x \ge 2$.  Can someone please explain this and breakdown $E[X],E[X^2]$?

> $f(x)=
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{l}
> 0 \text{ for x < 1}\\ 
> (x-1) \text{ for } 1 \le x <2\\ 
> 0 \text{ for } x \ge 2
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420756/finding-a-pdf-given-a-strictly-right-continuous-cdf

Answer (score 3):

The CDF as given explicitly states that Pr{ X < 1 } = 0, so the answer to your first question is NO, it is not ½.

However, the CDF jumps from 0 to ½ at X = 1. Therefore we know that Pr{ X = 1 } = ½.

I think this will be enough to get you started on the answer. I could work it all out for you, but it looks like a homework problem so I think I will stop here.